# How to Stop Image Capturing & Video Capturing in Windows while Playing Encrypted Video in Java

Tags: java, windows, image, video-capture

I want to know how to Stop User to Capture Screen or Download Encrypted Video in Windows.

I tried hard but nothing found.

can DRM help me???

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any way to prevent screen capturing. Screen capturing is like recording signals being sent to the monitor or display. Some or the other way people can find ways to record either using screen capture software or by recording output from the monitor wires.

**One possible strategy to prevent "Downloading Encrypted Video" is below: **

If you have lately observed youtube on a low speed network, you can see that the player does not load the entire video. It loads one section at a time and once the video has played till a  particular point it loads the next section and so on so forth. May before loading the next section you may adopt a security measure so that the video is never downloaded fully.

Comment: thanks for Reply but the Problem is if user will click on Backward to play then user will not able to play the Video in Previous State becuase it has been removed or Replaced.

Comment: Saraf you can easily overcome this, incorporate solution to this issue in your design. Simply check for session elements and permit access when the user wants to play video in previous state or from previous section. Just watch any youtube video properly.. I think fairly you can stop users from downloading content using some bots by this method.

Comment: Only Print Screen Can Not Prevent My Application from Coping so i am using Java Clipboard Library to Clear Clipboard of System every 100 Milliseconds so print-screen & Copy will not Work.